# SAS nested do loops with arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, sas, nested-loops

Having problems understanding the following code.  This snippet is supposed to output a data set that compares target values (`sasuser.ctargets`) to actual values (`sasuser.monthsum`).  Observations are matched by month and year and populated to the `targets` array.  The code works exactly as it should, but to my mind it shouldn't.

Look at the nested DO loop:

`Targets` is indexed in the nested DO loop by `year` and `j`.  I understand that the outer loop uses three iterations (`i=1 to 3`): one for each value of the year variable(1997-1999).  `Year`, however, is declared outside of the DO loop.  So if the automatic variable `_n_` creates the target array on the first iteration of the DO loop, how the hell does the `targets` array populate correctly for years 1998 and 1999 which are not read until subsequent iterations of the DATA step?  How is it that `year` works as an iterator?

```
data work.lookup1;
    array targets(1997:1999,12) _temporary_;
    if _n_=1 then do i=1 to 3;
        set sasuser.ctargets;
        array mnth(*) Jan--Dec;
        do j=1 to dim(mnth);
            targets(year,j)=mnth(j);
        end;
    end;
    set sasuser.monthsum(keep=salemon revcargo monthno);
    year=input(substr(salemon,4),4.);
    ctarget=targets(year,monthno);
    format ctarget dollar15.2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this works is if the variable `YEAR` is in the dataset `SASUSER.CTARGETS`.

Comment: Ah, so the iteration comes from the number of variables?  Each row has 12 month vales + year. First iteration: 12months for 1997. 2nd iteration: values 13-24 for 1998 and so on?  Now it makes sense. Thanks 